# AS3 Preloader which loads itself, not an external swf

Tags: actionscript-3, preloader, internal

How can I create a preloader which does this? I have seen many examples of code to load an external swf, but never something that loads itself.

Thanks for the help, this is driving me crazy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternatively ...
You can try FlashDevelop's Preloader template, makes it really easy

Comment: Wow, thats a great tool. I'll test it out fast, see if I can't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple. First you need to move everything except the preloader *off* the first frame.

Everything else is basically the same as an external preloader - the only difference is that you're checking the current and total size of the current movie, rather than a separate one.

Comment: http://sara-intop.blogspot.com/search/label/Preloading%20in%20FlashCS3 Its borrowed unfortunately, I am still new to Flash.

Comment: As a reference, here's the first result I got with a quick google for "AS3 Preloader": http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=151850

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, upon loading it shows "1" in the textfield and the "bar" doesn't change size.