# AS3 Preloader Internal or External?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, preloader

I was wondering what the best way to load my flash game would be. I know how to make an external preloader, but if I want to upload the .swf of the game to a site like newgrounds, Im guessing I need an internal preloader.

I've tried a few times but my game only displays after the swf is 100% loaded. While its loading I just see white screen with grey "..." which im guessing is built into the flash player.

I have a .fla called AsteroidsGame.fla which has a library of some classes, and the game's structure is coded into a .as file called AsteroidsGame.as. Maybe this is causing issues? I dont know, but I'd really appreciate any help getting a preloader up and running.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204843/as3-preloader-which-loads-itself-not-an-external-swf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, when loading, the flash player will start on frame 1, and will continue to sit there until all the data on frame 1 has been loaded.  Only then will it proceed to the next frame.  You can get a detailed report of how many bytes of data is exported to each frame by checking the "Generate Build Report" checkbox in the "Flash" tab under "File->Publisher Settings"

To get a simple loading display going, add a TextField named "loader_txt" in frame 1, and add this code in action:

```
  stop();

  this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);

  function loading(e:Event):void{

      var total:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
      var loaded:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;

      loader_txt.text = Math.floor((loaded/total)*100)+ "%";

    if (total == loaded){
      play();
      this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);
    }

  }
```

To make sure your assets and actionscript code are exported beyond frame 1 so above code can kick in immediately when flash movie begins to load, go to "File->Publish Settings", select "Flash" tab, and click on "Settings..." button to the right of "Script".  A dialog should show up.  In that dialog, under "Export classes in frame:", enter 2.

For assets in library, you may need to do similar thing.  Right click on a library asset and select properties, and you'll see the option to uncheck "Export in frame 1".  If you uncheck it (which means flash movie can start to play before this asset is loaded), you will have to make sure you have a reference to that symbol somewhere beyond frame 1 in the timeline, otherwise Flash will omit it from the compilation.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, "Settings..." button to the right of "Script". A dialog should show up. In that dialog, under "Export classes in frame:", enter 2." is exactly what i was looking for. Now I know why I was having problems. It is set to 1 right now.

Comment: +1, your answer was better than mine :)  I was trying to think of the rules for exporting to a different frame than the first but couldn't remember well enough to advise.  Too early for my brain this morning :P

Comment: Alright, despite this, I am still having the same issue. FYI im also getting a warning even though I have already done what it is asking: "Fonts should be embedded for any text that may be edited at runtime, other than text with the "Use Device Fonts" setting. Use the Text > Font Embedding command to embed fonts."

Comment: It looks like the TextField you just dropped down is using a font that is not a system font, and requires embedding.  What version of Flash IDE are you using?  Newer Flash IDE has a "TLF Text" in addition to a "Classic Text" option.  To simplify, use Classic Text for now and set it to Use Device Fonts.

Comment: As for the preloader itself, did you try "Generate Size Report" and see if bulk of your data is still on frame 1?  Maybe helpful if you paste the result here too.

Comment: Frame # 1 -  Frame Bytes 9160   -  Total Bytes 9160 -   Scene Scene 1 /-/-/ Frame # 2  - Frame Bytes 48012   -   Total Bytes 57172  -  Scene Scene 1 (AS 3.0 Classes Export Frame)

Comment: ALSO some debugging info: When I just changed the export classes prompt back to frame 1. My assets loaded fine. And the Silom font was loaded properly.

Comment: It appears the Silom embedding was a mistake on my part. But still, when I set the export classes to frame two, none of my library assets that are supposed to be displayed through my classes are displayed, and neither is the font.

Comment: sorry for all this reading but more info: When I simulate download, I still get the white screen with the "..." and the text with the percent loaded displays only at 100% loaded on frame 2 even though the preloader code with the percent text is pasted on frame 1.

Comment: And as I stated in my original post, the main .fla is AsteroidsGame.fla and it is also a class called AsteroidsGame.as. (Maybe this is causing issues?)

Comment: Although manto's answer is perfect and very well explained, I would go with an external preloader... Changing the export frame is not at all as straight-forward as it seems, and your fla project will be cleaner and easier to work with. As for submitting your game to different game sites, AFAIK they will always provide a way to upload several files, and if not, you should be able to submit only the preloader and load the game from your own servers.

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you know why my pre loader doesn't display until frame 2 though? I have it set to export classes at frame 2. The above comments describe what im seeing. Even though I will switch to an external preloader, I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

External.  With the proper security permissions you should be able to load content from a remote location into a shell in most any environment.

The delay you see when loading with an internal loader is likely caused by library assets your are exporting for actionscript at runtime.  They will get exported to the first frame.  until that frame loads you can't see any preloading and your preloader logic will jump to the percent loaded of that first frame once it has finished exporting those assets.